# Rails alternative to joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, left-join

I would like to show a post. This works so far. I just did this:

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    render :json => @post
  end
```

But now I would like to add the user who created this post, the tags, likes and comments. I am not sure how to do that with Rails. A few years ago I would have did a very big `join` so my object has all information in it like username, email, from the user who posted this one post. But I am asking myself if there is a better way to do this? Take a look at the Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :comments
  has_many   :likes, as: :likeable, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

Comment: Are you looking for options like `includes` , `eager_load` or `preload` in order to avoid N+1 query ?

Comment: @dp7 I am not sure :D I would just like to show the whole post in a view. My question is should I do a big left join so my var `@post` has all infos about the comments, likes and the user or is there a better way? Maybe just write a new line like: `@comments= Comment.where(:post_id => @post.id`

Comment: I think you should use any of the eager loading method and access all other relevant data from the `@post` object. Like you can get comments as `@post.comments`

Comment: @dp7 Ok, I am just trying right now but I am getting this error: `undefined method "eager_load" for #<Post:0x007fdc5a857ee0> `

Comment: Please add the code snippet you just tried.

Comment: @dp7 `@post = Post.where(id: params[:id]).first.eager_load(:user, :comments, :likes, :tags)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eagerload is the way for you

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id]).eager_load(:user, :comments, :likes, :tags)
    render :json => {
             :post => @post,
             :user => @post.user,
             :comments => @post.comments,
             :tags => @post.tags
     }
  end
```

Now if you want to go one level more deep to find who commented or who liked assuming your comment and like model will have belongs_to relationship to a user you can make this query

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id]).eager_load(:user, :comments => :user, :likes => :user, :tags)
```

Comment: Yes yes yes! This looks promising. I will test it and get back to you. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm, my rails cannot find this method: `undefined method "eager_load" for #<Post:0x007fdc5a857ee0>`

Comment: yes replace find_by with where and then select the first record, its weird why this did't work with find_by

Comment: still the same error: `@post = Post.where(id: params[:id]).first.eager_load(:user, :comments, :likes, :tags)`

Comment: This worked: `@post = Post.eager_load(:user, :comments, :likes, :tags).where(id: params[:id]).first` Thank you!

Comment: I wanted to go one level more deep, but your code snippet did not work. First of all I get a error like this: `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>`. After I moved the tags and likes more left, I did not get any errors but it seems like it didn't do anything. The @post.comments looks the same like before. My code: `@post = Post.eager_load(:user, :tags, :likes, :comments => :user).find_by(id: params[:id])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includes` or `eager_load` or `preload` to eager load your `@post`:

```
@post = Post.eager_load(:user, :comments, :likes, :tags).where(id: params[:id]).first
```